# Find the nth term of a geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I realized I forgot most of my high school maths. Earlier today I asked a question and I thought I understood it until I looked at it again.

I'm trying to find the 100th term of the following sequence:

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\small a_0 = 1}$$
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\small a_n = a_{n-1} + 2^{-n}}$$

1. How can you quickly arrive to the fact that this is a geometric series? If I'm looking at the first few terms $1, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{7}{4}$, normally to find the common ratio you divide a term by its predecessor right? So $r = \frac{\frac{7}{4}}{\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{7}{6}$ which does not hold.
2. The answer for getting the 100th term is supposed to be $\frac{2^{101} - 1}{2^{100}}$ but I'm not quite sure how to arrive to this conclusion.

I would really appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Comment: For clarity, this isn't a [geometric *sequence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression), although the successive added terms are, so it forms a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n=1+\frac12+\frac14+\cdots+\frac1{2^n}$,

so each term in the sequence $(a_n)$ is the sum of the first $n+1$ terms of a geometric series.

Using the formula for the sum of the first $n+1$ terms of a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula),

$a_n=\dfrac{1-\dfrac1{2^{n+1}}}{1-\dfrac12}=\dfrac{2^{n+1}-1}{2^n}$.

Comment: But shouldn't you take the terms? e.g. $a_0 = 1$, $a_1 = \frac{3}{2}$, $a_2 = \frac{7}{4}$? Why won't dividing the nth term by the n-1th term give you the common ratio here?

Comment: $(a_n)$ is a sequence of partial sums of a geometric series, not a [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression); $1, \frac12, \frac14,...$ is a geometric progression (each successive term obtained by multiplying the previous term by $\frac12$)